# Can I remove a set of ManyToMany objects using SafeDeleteModel?

Tags: django, soft-delete

Soft_delete_cascade was applied to the entire model using the [django-safedelete](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-safedelete) library.

However, if you remove the corresponding many to many object as in the code below, it is not deleted from the set of objects.

What should I do?

```py
# models.py
from django.db import models
from safedelete import SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE, HARD_DELETE
from safedelete.models import SafeDeleteModel


class Post(SafeDeleteModel):
    _safedelete_policy: int = SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE

    category = models.CharField("카테고리", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField("제목", max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField("생성일시", auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField("수정시간", auto_now=True)

    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag", through="TagPostAssociation", related_name="posts")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"글(ID:{self.id}/제목:{self.title})"


class Tag(SafeDeleteModel):
    _safedelete_policy: int = SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE

    value = models.CharField("태그 값", max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField("생성일시", auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField("수정시간", auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = verbose_name_plural = "태그"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"태그(ID:{self.id}/값:{self.value})"


class TagPostAssociation(SafeDeleteModel):
    _safedelete_policy: int = HARD_DELETE

    tag = models.ForeignKey(to=Tag, verbose_name="태그", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(to=Post, verbose_name="글", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField("생성일시", auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField("수정시간", auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = verbose_name_plural = "글-태그"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"글{self.post.id})-태그({self.tag.id})"
```

```bash
>>> post = Post.objects.get(id=2)
>>> tag = Tag.objects.get(id=2)
>>> post.tags.all()
<SafeDeleteQueryset [<Tag: 태그(ID:2/값:hair)>, <Tag: 태그(ID:1/값:test)>]>
>>> post.tags.remove(tag)
>>> post.tags.all()
<SafeDeleteQueryset [<Tag: 태그(ID:2/값:hair)>, <Tag: 태그(ID:1/값:test)>]>
```

I tried to delete the many to many object using the m2m_changed signal, but it didn't work.

Comment: maybe try changing in `class TagPostAssociation(SafeDeleteModel):`
to use `soft_delete_cascade` instead of `hard_delete`?

Comment: yes i did When using HARD_DELETE, it is normally removed.

Comment: But I want to soft delete many to many objects.

Comment: Can you please share your signal approach?